# Guzzle HTTP Client - statusCode

Tags: guzzle

I am getting some cURL data using Guzzle Framework.

Code

```
$client = new Client();
$request = $client->get($url);
$response = $request->send();
$status = $response->getStatusCode();
```

After **X** requests I am getting 403 forbidden error code, mostly more than 150.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Is the API/URI that you're calling subject to rate limits? I know that the Twitter API used to implement a maximum rate of approximately 150 requests per hour before it started to return an error message. The solution is to implement caching at your end if the situation is appropriate for the data to be cached.

Without knowing the service that you're calling it is difficult to offer much more help currently.